# Find the volume of a cone whose length of its side is $R$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

How can i compute the volume of a cone whose length of its side is $R$ and the vertex of the cone forms an angle $2θ$ .

The top cone is a cap of a sphere of radius $R$.

[image]

I tried to solve first in 2 dimension and then use solid of revolution:

[image]

Some help please to find the volume of this cone.

Comment: Can you describe some ideas you have about it? You tagged it with 
"integration". What might you integrate over?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap#Volume_and_surface_area

Comment: Why have you asked the same question twice?

Comment: here is my work , more explicit and my tried

Comment: You should probably edit the first one to include your work since there is already an answer there. (possible duplicate of [The volume of a cone whose length of its side is $R$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766974/the-volume-of-a-cone-whose-length-of-its-side-is-r) )

Comment: I have merged this question with your previous one.

Answer (score 0):

You added the tags "calculus" and "integration", so I am assuming that you are familiar with these techniques.

**Hint**: Set up a volume (triple) integral with $1$ as the integrand:

$$\iiint_S1dV$$

Using spherical coordinates, what will the bounds of integration be?  Of course, remember to include the Jacobian determinant since we are not integrating with rectangular coordinates.

Alternatively, this is a 3D analogue to the question: What is the area of a sector of a circle swept out by a given angle?

Comment: What warranted the downvote out of curiousity?  If there's something wrong, let me know so I can fix it for future readers and the OP.